# Cumulative distribution function of sample average of size 4

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ ~ $U[0;2\theta]$. How to find $P(\frac{X_{(2)}+X_{(3)}}{2}<t)$?

My attempt is here:

$P(\frac{X_{(2)}+X_{(3)}}{2}<t)=P(\frac{X_2+X_3}{2}<t|X_2<X_3)=\frac{P(\frac{X_2+X_3}{2}<t,X_2<X_3)}{P(X_2<X_3)}=2P(\frac{X_2+X_3}{2}<t,X_2<X_3)=\int_0^{2\theta-X_3}{P(\frac{X_3+s+X_3}{2}<t,X_2=X_3+s)ds}=\int_0^{2\theta-X_3}\int_0^tP(X_3=\xi-0.5s,X_2=\xi+s/2)d\xi ds==\int_0^{2\theta-X_3}\int_0^tP(X_3=\xi-0.5s)P(X_2=\xi+s/2)d\xi ds$

So here I want to substitute the pdf, which is equal to $\frac{1}{2\theta}$, but it's obvious that I will have $X_3$ in the final expression, so I messed up something somewhere.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can get proper spacing in conditional probabilities by using `\mid` instead of `|`. You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant when mixing integrals, fractions and subscripts. If the displayed equation is too long for a line, you can insert a line break with `\\`.

Comment: More generally, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: The first equality is already wrong – $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$ could also be $X_1$ and $X_4$; they depend on the values and ordering of all four variables.